Understanding Bremsstrahlung computation in Peskin & Schroeder book
In an introduction to QFT by Peskin & Schroeder page 181 there is an approximation for the following expression:
$$\mathcal{I}(\textbf{v},\textbf{v'}) = \int{\frac{d\Omega_\hat{k}}{4\pi}\frac{2(1-\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{v'})}{(1-\hat{k}\cdot \textbf{v} )(1-\hat{k} \cdot \textbf{v'})}}$$
where $|\textbf{v}|, |\textbf{v'}|<1$.
The way they approximate this integral is by evaluting it around the pick points: where $\hat{k}$ is aligned to  $\textbf{v}$ or $\textbf{v'}$.
Then we can approximate area by the following integral (for example around  $\textbf{v}$):
$$\mathcal{I}(\textbf{v},\textbf{v'})\approx \int^{cos\hspace{0.3mm}\theta=1}_{\hat{k} \cdot \textbf{v}=\textbf{v'}\cdot\textbf{v}}{d\hspace{0.3mm}cos\hspace{0.3mm}\theta\frac{(1-\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{v'})}{(1-\hat{k}\cdot \textbf{v} )(1-\hat{k} \cdot \textbf{v'})}}$$
where $\hat{k}\cdot \textbf{v} = v\hspace{0.3mm}cos\hspace{0.3mm}\theta$
But then they switch  $1- \hat{k} \cdot \textbf{v'}$ by $1-\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{v'}$ in the denominator for some reason, I guess that becase you can approximate $\hat{k}$ to be in the direction of $\textbf{v}$ but why is is it the same size?
Also later when they evaluate this integral to be $log(\frac{1-\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{v'}}{1-|\textbf{v}|})$ but I think they are missing $\frac{1}{v}$ times this result.
What am I missing?
